# Add Visual Studio "Open With" option for all file types

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'd like to add Notepad++ to the "Open With..." menu for all file types in Visual Studio 2013. I followed [these directions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hy2sthf1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to create it for one file (in my case, a .edmx file), but Notepad++ still does not appear as an available editor in any other type (e.g. .tt, .cd).

How do I add Notepad++ as an option for all file types, rather than adding it to each file type one by one? Many of the built-in editors (e.g. "JSON Edtior", "XML (Text) Editor") are available for all files, regardless of type, so it should be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I looked in the CurrentSettings.vssettings file, and found that the relevant settings are at `name="Environment_DefaultEditors"`, as in the following block:

```
<Category name="Environment_DefaultEditors" Category="{68161AEE-BCA8-4214-B2E4-7875263E49C5}" Package="{DA9FB551-C724-11d0-AE1F-00A0C90FFFC3}" RegisteredName="Environment_DefaultEditors" PackageName="Visual Studio Environment Package">
    <PropertyValue name="NumberOfMappings">0</PropertyValue>
    <PropertyValue name="NumberOfDefaultEditors">5</PropertyValue>
    <PropertyValue name="DefaultEditor&gt;0">cd&gt;0&gt;NoGuid&gt;NoGuid</PropertyValue>
    <PropertyValue name="DefaultEditor&gt;1">config&gt;0&gt;NoGuid&gt;NoGuid</PropertyValue>
    <PropertyValue name="DefaultEditor&gt;2">cs&gt;0&gt;NoGuid&gt;NoGuid</PropertyValue>
    <PropertyValue name="DefaultEditor&gt;3">edmx&gt;0&gt;NoGuid&gt;NoGuid&gt;1&gt;Notepad++?"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"</PropertyValue>
    <PropertyValue name="DefaultEditor&gt;4">tt&gt;0&gt;NoGuid&gt;NoGuid</PropertyValue>
</Category>
```

So the PropertyValues are only generated if you try "Open With..." for the file type at least once. Also, the settings really are only on a filetype-by-filetype basis; the "Default JSON Editor" and such are hardcoded into Visual Studio.

So barring a (possible) programmatic way to edit the settings file directly, this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty easy. I use VS2012 and it works for me. Pretty sure this is the same for VS2013. Make sure you pick the Notepad++.exe from the C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\ . 
You don't need any Arguments for the "Add Program" dialog box. Just specify the path to the Notepad++.exe and a friendly name. That's it.

Comment: I did that in the steps outlined in my question, but it did not add it to all file types.